# PHP Form - Problem with reply e-mail

Tags: php, email, forms, contacts, reply

The contact form is working just fine but I can't figure how to setup the "reply mail". The PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
// Get Data 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

// Send Message
mail( "Message from $name",
"Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $message\n",
"From: $name <forms@example.net>" );
?>
```

What I tried to do is replace "forms@example.com" with $email but for some reason it crashes and never sends anything.

Comment: When it "crashes" is an error produced?

Comment: Probably failing because you have not specified arguments correctly to `mail()` See the documentation: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it just the `Reply-to: reply@example.com` header you're missing in your mail headers block?  Also, looks like you're missing the first parameter to the `mail()` function, which should be the address it's sent to.

Add the `Reply-to` header into the third parameter to `mail()`.

```
// Send Message
mail($to_address, "Message from $name",
  // Message
  "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $message\n",
  // Additional headers
  "From: $name <forms@example.net>\r\nReply-to: reply@example.com"
);
```

**EDIT** I missed a comma in the question and thought the whole block was the message, including name & from.  Edited above.  I see you already had a header block.

Comment: You should separate the headers with `\r\n`.

Comment: I made the changes and replaced reply@example.com by $email but it's still showing <forms@example.net> in the reply field.

Comment: Please post the full email headers from the received message then.  Even better, post the full message headers and body.

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't see the EDIT. I'll try again and let you know.

Comment: I'll be back in half an hour or a few more. This last test worked but messed with the page.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the correct parameters for the mail function. Take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

In your case, it would be:

```
mail( $to,
$subject,
$message,
"From: $name <forms@example.net>" );
```

Assuming that you gave it a $to (which denotes who to send the email to) and a $subject (the subject of the email).

Answer (score 0):

Take this snippet:

```
 <?php
    //define the receiver of the email
    $to = 'youraddress@example.com';
    //define the subject of the email
    $subject = 'Test email';
    //define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
    $message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail.";
    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
    //send the email
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
    ?>
```

In your code, you missed the first argument, witch should be to who.